# What do you call a company in relation to its host commmunity?

Tags: antonyms, technical

This is a case of an oil company occupying a community for its operations. The community is its `host`, I believe. What is the company referred to in relationship to the community?
Generally, it should be `guest`. But, of course, that doesn't look right. I've checked [PowerThesaurus](http://www.powerthesaurus.org/host/antonyms). The closest I could get is `occupant` and `tenant` but I don't know, isn't there a technical term?

**EDIT**
In my particular case, it refers to a foreign oil company in a local community. I'm not really including the fruit sellers et al.

Comment: Every company location, large or small, public or private, exists in some community. Are you trying to describe them all?

Comment: @bib Yes, as long as it describes what they are to the community

Comment: Including the fruit stand run by a long time resident?

Comment: OK, let me edit the question to make it clear

Comment: Well, maybe *foreign company* will be most appropriate here.

Comment: I'd go with employer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an article called "[Dealing with Non-Resident Companies](http://www.canadianrealpropertylawblog.com/2014/03/dealing-with-non-resident-companies/)," on a blog called The Lay of the Land: Developments in Canadian Real Property Law, Michael Nienhuis refers to a foreign "guest" company doing business in a host community as a "non-resident tenant corporation." That may be the closest thing to a legal term for the phenomenon (at least in Canada) that exists, although I note that in Nienhuis's article the corporation so described is in fact a tenant paying rent to a resident Canadian landlord.

If I were trying to refer in neutral terms to the relationship between a local (and not especially wealthy) community and a large oil company whose headquarters are on another continent, I might describe the oil company as the community's "corporate tenant from overseas" or perhaps its "economically powerful new resident," and subsequently refer to it simply as "the tenant" or as the "oil company" or perhaps (once only) as "the multinational giant."

I wouldn't recommend repeatedly calling it a "non-resident tenant corporation," even if that is the most accurate term, to protect your readers from Glazed Eyes syndrome.

Answer (score 0):

Your choice depends on your goal. If you're writing an opinion piece, consider using connotation to your advantage. What I mean is, occupant in this case sounds more harsh and negative than guest. This can have a powerful subtle effect on the reader. I'm wondering if you specifically want to remain neutral here since you asked for a technical term though.

Comment: Yes, Joe, I want to remain neutral.